How to add a GET method to CoreWCF service
I am converting a WCF service from .net framework to .net core and using CoreWCF, I have my method decorated like so
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        Method = "GET", 
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, 
        UriTemplate= "MethodName?status={status}")]
    Task<ServiceResponse> MethodName(ServiceStatus status);

}

However, when I run the service the GET call always return 400 whereas the post call works. I added the wsdl to SoapUI and soapUI sends the request as post. What am I doing wrong here?

Install the Corewcf.webhttp package. Then use the webget feature.
Iservice.cs
using CoreWCF;
using CoreWCF.Web;
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace CoreWCFService1

    {
        [ServiceContract]
        public interface IWebApi
        {
            [OperationContract]
            [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/hello")]
            string PathEcho();
        }
    
        public class WebApi : IWebApi
        {
            public string PathEcho() => "Hello World!";
        }
    }

Program.cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
{
    options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
    options.ListenLocalhost(7119);
});

builder.Services.AddServiceModelWebServices();

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseServiceModel(builder =>
{
    builder.AddService<WebApi>();
    builder.AddServiceWebEndpoint<WebApi, IWebApi>("api");
});

app.Run();

PostmanTest:


It did not work as-is for me. The main difference I see is you used
builder.AddServiceWebEndpoint<WebApi, IWebApi>("api");
where as I used
.AddServiceEndpoint<UI.WebService.MCSWCFService, UI.WebService.IMCSWCFService>(
new BasicHttpBinding()
{
ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
},
"");
AddServiceWebEndPoint vs. AddServiceEndPoint.

@Qudoos Yes, the AddServiceWebEndpoint is needed for a WCFservice with GET method. Remember that WCF defaults to SOAP, which only uses POST requests. If you want to use HTTP methods, you also need a WebHttpBinding instead of BasicHttpBinding.
